# CodingQuestion, find all missing numbers

Tags: arrays, sorting

```
1) nums[i] != nums[nums[i]-1]
2) i != nums[i]-1
```

There is any difference between 1) and 2)?
I can't figure it out any difference btw them, but Instead of 1) , if I have code 2), program have error.

Here is brief explanation of my problem.
This is coding problem which finding all missing numbers in an unsorted array which containing numbers taken from the range 1 to n. The array can have duplicates, so it means soome numbers will be missing. ( - which I want to get.)

```
Input: [2, 3, 1, 8, 2, 3, 5, 1] Output: 4, 6, 7 
The array should have all numbers from 1 to 8, due to duplicates 4, 6, and 7 are missing.
```

I know that there are definitely more efficient solutions for this problem, but here I want to solve this using cyclic sort pattern, 
which using the fact that

> In this problem, the numbers are ranged from '1' to 'n', so    we
>   can place each number at its correct place.    for example, index 0 :
>   1 / index 1: 2 / index 2: 3.... so on.
>
> ```
> public static List<Integer> findNumbers(int[] nums) {
> int i = 0;
> while (i < nums.length) {
>   if (nums[i] != nums[nums[i] - 1])
>     swap(nums, i, nums[i] - 1);
>   else
>     i++;
> }
>
> List<Integer> missingNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
> for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
>   if (nums[i] != i + 1)
>     missingNumbers.add(i + 1);
>
> return missingNumbers;   }
> ```

So back to my question  I cant find any difference btw 1) and 2). 
Cause always index 0 should have 1, index 1 should have 2, index 2 should have 3. so that I think i can simply use the pattern : 2) i != nums[i]-1 instead of 1).

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
while (i < nums.length) {
  if (nums[i] != nums[nums[i] - 1])
    swap(nums, i, nums[i] - 1);
  else
    i++;
}
```

Let's figure out what can goes wrong in this solution. The algorithm got the value 10 of element 0 and value of element 9 (because `nums[i] - 1` is 9). let it be `10` for example. And algorithm goes forward because the values are equals. As you can see this is an answer to your question:

`nums[i] != nums[nums[i]-1]` - compares with a random number from the source array. It causes really funny infinity loop for your example and numbers 2 and 3 on first two positions.

`i != nums[i] - 1` - compares current value with the index that really has to be placed in this position.

Also you may easily get the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the array will have the length less than maximum number. But as far as i can see it is not a part of the exercise.

As I can see you are trying to solve the issue without an additional array. But you may find easier solution here https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2018/04/how-to-find-k-missing-numbers-in-array-java.html

Answer (score 0):

The conditions below are not same -

`1) nums[i] != nums[nums[i]-1]
 2) i != nums[i]-1`

Example:

```
let i = 0
const nums = [2, 3, 1, 8, 2, 3, 5, 1];

nums[i] != nums[nums[i]-1];
nums[0] != nums[nums[0]-1];
2 != nums[2-1];
2 != 3;
```

In this, you are checking element at current index with the element at next index.

```
i != nums[i]-1
0 != nums[0]-1;
0 != 2-1
0 != 1;
```

In this case, your are checking if the `current index` is not equal to element at the current index in array minus one.

Your `not equal to` logic will not work. In order to do proper sorting you have to use `greater than(>) or less than(<)`. For ascending order, swapping should only me made if current index item is greater than next one.